# css3 Transition to whole div

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/nv4587qd/

Here is my code. The transition on hover link 'more information' is working, but i want to make whole 'hidden' class to work like that.

```
.content {
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hidden a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hidden a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.content:hover > .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go for opacity: 0 to opacity: 1; You cannot transition display.

Answer (score 2):

Use `opacity` instead of `display`. Visually the same effect, but can be targeted with transitions.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/nv4587qd/1/)